# When are Nvidia drivers updated?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

How often are `nvidia-current` and `nvidia-current-updates` packages updated, and when do they usually become available?

Comment: This is entirely depend on the nvidia developers.

Answer (score 1):

According to this http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_display_archive.html it looks like about once a month, but as Ravi has said, it is really up to the nvidia developers. They do not follow a strict release schedule. I believe when using Jockey (the Additional Drivers dialog), they are updated as they come out.